# How to merge or concat to byte [ ] arrays of PDF's type in java but am getting pdf1 as output

Tags: java, pdf

Below are my two byte arrays and am concating or merging two byte array but am always getting pdf1 as a output file merge is not happening.

```
byte[] pdfData = this.service.generatePdf1(Id, countryid, extno,language);;
byte[] pdfData1 = this.service.generatePdf2(templateType, qe.getProductId(), countryid,language);;

byte[] pdf= new byte[pdfData.length + pdfData1.length];
```

Comment: Why do you think just concatenating byte arrays would somehow merge the PDF files into one? I don't know much about PDF, but I'm pretty sure the PDF format defines where it ends, so it will not read beyond the content of the first file (as an aside, in your code you're not actually doing that, you're only creating an empty array of the size of the other two arrays)

Comment: PDF has a complex structure, so you need a dedicated library to do that.